# How to display the part of the hierarchy depending on selection object in editor window ui panel with the option expand the children?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
private void OnGUI()
    {
        EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
        {
            scroll = EditorGUILayout.BeginScrollView(scroll, GUILayout.Width(200), GUILayout.Height(500));
            {
                GameObject[] gameObjects = GameObject.FindObjectsOfType(typeof(GameObject)) as GameObject[];
                foreach (GameObject go in gameObjects)
                {
                    // Start with game objects without any parents
                    if (go.transform.parent == null)
                    {
                        // Show the object and its children
                        ShowObject(go, gameObjects);
                    }
                }
            }
            EditorGUILayout.EndScrollView();
        }
        EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();

        void ShowObject(GameObject parent, GameObject[] gameObjects)
        {
            // Show entry for parent object
            if (UnityEditor.EditorGUILayout.Foldout(true, parent.name))
            {
                foreach (GameObject go in gameObjects)
                {
                    // Find children of the parent game object
                    if (go.transform.parent == parent.transform)
                    {
                        ShowObject(go, gameObjects);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The display the whole hierarchy on the editor window ui panel.

but i have some problems :

In this line i can set true or false but how can i make that i will be able to expand/collapse it when clicking on the arrow like in the hierarchy it self ?

How to make that when expanding it will show it in a tree like in the hierarchy the children like in a tree ? The same as in the hierarchy.

How to make that it will show only from a selection object, when selecting object cliking on object in the hierarhcy display the hierarchy from the selected object and not the whole hierarchy like now ?

Comment: Are you looking for this https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/TreeViewAPI.html ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use `Foldout`, you need a boolean value that can track the expansion/contraction.

```
isOpen = EditorGUILayout.Foldout(isOpen, "Expand");

if (isOpen)
{
    GUILayout.Label("Expanded content");
}
```

This would take a fair amount of architecture to work as a hierarchy view. In your context it could look something like..

```
if (thisObj.ParentObj.ExpandedInEditor)
{
    thisObj.ExpandedInEditor = EditorGUILayout.Foldout(thisObj.ExpandedInEditor, thisObj.name);

    if (thisObj.ExpandedInEditor)
    {
        // Draw object here
    }
}
```